# Angular 2 Newsfeed similar to facebook

Tags: angular

I have to create a page where we will show posts and comments similar to Facebook. I was wondering how to design this in angular 2.

Is it possible to have list of component where container component can pass data in loop to generate page i.e. NewsfeedComponent having list of PostComponent

Comment: Of course it is, just use e.g. `<my-post-component *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post"></my-post-component>` inside the news feed component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create post wrapper/parent component which has list of child components like image, title, comments, like, share etc. you can loop thru parent component and pass the data to respective component.

`<post-component *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post"></post-component>`

post will have object of child type.